# How to use <select><option value={true}> in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, select

I have the following code:

```
<option value={false}>{getIntl('modals.users.suspended.unlocked')}</option>
<option value={true}>{getIntl('modals.users.suspended.locked')}</option>
```

but this returns the following error:

```
Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string | number | string[] | undefined'.
```

I'm using `TypeScript` and in the `Interface` the value for this element is set to have a `boolean` data type. Is there a way to use `true`/`false` in `select` dropdown?

Comment: I think you probably should use "true" or "false" and cast it to boolean whenever you will use

Answer (score 6):

The `value` attribute of `option` accepts only string or number types, what you have provided is a boolean.

Try instead wrapping it in double or single quotes. Like: `"true"` or `"false"`, which are strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use 0 1 number type instead. 0 for false and 1 for true when type transfer

Answer (score 0):

The select option value must be a string or number, If you want to insert a boolean value you may use string-wise **"true"/ "false"** else you may use number type **1 for true and 2 for false.**

Don't use **0 for false** because it' selects the option but **doesn't appear** in the **input Box**.

Alternatively, you can use **1 for true** and **2 for false.**

For Example

```
let Priority = [
  {value:1, label: "True"},
  {value:2, label: "False"}
]
```